# How can I redirect the elementor "add to cart" button direct to the check out page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor, woocommerce-theming

I have tried this codes but no result. The add to cart button still redirecting to cart page but I want it redirect to the checkout page.

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'misha_skip_cart_redirect_checkout' );
 
function misha_skip_cart_redirect_checkout( $url ) {
    return wc_get_checkout_url();
}

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url', 'misha_fix_for_individual_products', 10, 2 );
function misha_fix_for_individual_products( $add_to_cart_url, $product ){
 
    if( $product->get_sold_individually() // if individual product
    && WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product->id ) ) // if in the cart
    && $product->is_purchasable() // we also need these two conditions
    && $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $add_to_cart_url = wc_get_checkout_url();
    }
 
    return $add_to_cart_url;
 
}

    add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'misha_remove_add_to_cart_message' );
 
function misha_remove_add_to_cart_message( $message ){
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code which redirect to checkout page after product added to cart:

```
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'zeal_redirect_to_checkout');

function zeal_redirect_to_checkout() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
    return $checkout_url;
}
```